# R caret training - but each sample has three separate measurements and I want to use majority vote to predict

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a very specific datasets with 50 people. Each person has a response (sex) and ~2000 measurements of some biological stuff.
We have three independent replicates from each person, so 3 rows pr. person.

I can easily use caret and groupKFold() to keep each person in either training or test sets - that works fine.

Then  I simply predict each replicate separately (so 3 prediction pr person).

I want to use these three prediction together and make a combined prediction pr. person either using majority vote and/or some other scheme.

I.e. - so for each person I get the 3 predictions and predict the response to be the one with most votes. That's pretty easy to do for the final model, but it should also be used in the tuning step (i.e. in the cross validation picking parameter values).

I think I can do that in the summaryFunction=... when calling caret::trainControl() but I would simply like to ask:

**Is there a simpler way of doing this?**

I have googled around - but I keep failing in finding people with similar problems. And I really hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think there is a simpler way than writing a custom summary function.

Comment: Hi @missuse - thanks a lot. Then I will just continue in that direction. Thanks a lot!